# PYQT directory dialog opens twice

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a function which gets the directory by a button.  Whenever I want to use the directory thats retrieved with other functions, it makes the open dialog appear again.  Any way to work around this.  I created another function to call that will hopefully avoid it but still isnt working.  Here is what im trying..

```
def selectFilecsvtoxml(self):


    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, caption="Pick a folder", directory=QtCore.QDir.currentPath())


    print directory + " this si dirrrrectory"
    self.listDirPath.setText(directory)

    for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        if not file_name.startswith("."):

            print (file_name) +  "   this is selectFilcestoxml"

    return directory


def showDirectory(self):
    showDir = self.selectFilecsvtoxml
    dir = str(showDir)
    print showDir + " this is the files from this class which makes dumbpop"
    print dir + "  this might fix it"
    return dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a function which shows a dialog and returns the directory chosen by the user. The purpose of the function is to ask the user something you don't know, here a path to a folder.
Once you know the directory, there is no need to ask the user again: you shouldn't call this function more than once.

Instead, you should **store the value** that the user gave you. Here's a simple example:

```
class myWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        ...
        self.directory=None
        self.button=QtGui.QPushButton("choose a folder")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.select)

   def select(self):
       self.directory=QtGui.QFileDialog...

   def do_stuff_with_directory(self):
       print(self.directory)
```

At the beginning, `self.directory` is None because you don't know what it should be. When the user click the "chose a folder" button, `self.directory` is set to their choice.
Since it's an attribute of `MyWidget`, you can use it in any of it's method. You should just check that it is not None before using it.

---

I saw that you wrote `self.listDirPath.setText(directory)`.
So another way to get the chosen directory in any function would be:

```
directory=self.listDirPath.text()
```

Comment: I would suggest avoiding storing the directory as an instance attribute unless it is necessary. You could equally define a method `def do_stuff_with_directory(self, directory)` and pass the directory in whenever you call it. In my opinion, that is more transparent and modular.

Comment: How would the `select` method look like ? I don't see how one can call `do_stuff` at any time without an instance attribute.

Comment: what if the function is in another class?

Comment: I guess my problem is that being in another class it has this problem